# The method getText() is undefined for the type String. Regarding to get content from EditText

Tags: java, android

Here is my code. I'm receiving `The method getText() is undefined for the type String` and cannot solve it by my own.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        EditText ETtitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETtitle);
        EditText ETcontent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETcontent);
        button.setOnClickListener(new buttonOnClickListener());

        }
    public class buttonOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ETtitle = ETtitle.getText().toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I checked the other question but I don't understand, but after I asked I understood it so it is specified somehow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
String ETtitle = ETtitle.getText().toString();
```

to

```
String ETtitleStr = ETtitle.getText().toString();
```

because **ETtitle** already defined as `edittext`

and define `EditText ETtitle` as class member.

i.e. simply rewrite your code as

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


   private  EditText ETtitle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        ETtitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETtitle);
        EditText ETcontent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETcontent);
        button.setOnClickListener(new buttonOnClickListener());

        }
    public class buttonOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ETtitleStr = ETtitle.getText().toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: New error just came up: When I changed it like yours, it reminds me"ETtitle cannot be resolved"

Comment: This format is much more formal than mine. I like it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

you are redefining  `ETtitle` locally

change

```
String ETtitle = ETtitle.getText().toString();
```

into

```
String editTextContent = ETtitle.getText().toString();
```

Comment: New error just came up: When I changed it like yours, it reminds me"ETtitle cannot be resolved"

Comment: declare  EditText ETtitle as member class